Validatation Message Not working With Blazor Using Generic
In Blazor 8 Web Assembly (maybe other hosting models), ValidationMessage does not display when using Generic model in the component. Here is an example. Looks like I have to do something with the For expression but what?
    @typeparam TModel where TModel : class, new()

    <EditForm Context="editFormComponent" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" Model="@model">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <h4>Validation Summary</h4>
        <ValidationSummary />
        @foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(model)?.ToString();
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input @onchange='((e) => HandleValueChanged(e, property.Name))'
                               type="text"
                               value=@propertyValue
                               class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h5>Validation Message</h5>
            <ValidationMessage For=@(() => property.Name) />


I want to look like this:


You need to build a custom ValidationMessage component to handle the way you provide the field name.  It's not easy to build the For expression generically, but you can provide the Model and FieldName that the component derives internally from the expression.
Here's BlazorValidationMessage based on the ValidationMessage code base.
@implements IDisposable

@foreach (var message in _validationMessages)
{
    <div class="validation-message" @attributes="this.AdditionalAttributes">
        @message
    </div>
}

@code {
    private EditContext? _previousEditContext;
    private FieldIdentifier _fieldIdentifier;
    private IEnumerable<string> _validationMessages => CurrentEditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier);

    [CascadingParameter] EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public object? Model { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string? FieldName { get; set; }
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (CurrentEditContext is null|| this.FieldName is null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The Edit Context and/or FieldName are missing!");

        _fieldIdentifier = new(this.Model ?? this.CurrentEditContext.Model, this.FieldName);

        if (CurrentEditContext != _previousEditContext)
        {
            DetachValidationStateChangedListener();
            CurrentEditContext.OnValidationStateChanged += this.OnValidationStateChanged;
            _previousEditContext = CurrentEditContext;
        }
    }

    private void OnValidationStateChanged(object? sender, ValidationStateChangedEventArgs e)
        => StateHasChanged();

    private void DetachValidationStateChangedListener()
    {
        if (_previousEditContext != null)
            _previousEditContext.OnValidationStateChanged -= OnValidationStateChanged;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        DetachValidationStateChangedListener();
    }
}

Which you then use like this in GenericComponent
        @foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(model)?.ToString();
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input @onchange='((e) => HandleValueChanged(e, property.Name))'
                               type="text"
                               value=@propertyValue
                               class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h5>Validation Message</h5>
            <BlazorValidationMessage FieldName="@property.Name"/>
     }

ValidationMessage code - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs
